# XNA significant loss in fps by just adding a few hundred thousand more triangles?

Tags: xna, c#

I've got a minecraftish game that's running nice and smooth with a total of 9.3 million triangles, about 50-70fps average.  Then if I try to render 9.9 million triangles I get hell and it drops to < 1 fps.  I'm drawing them exactly the same way, it's definitely the drawing as I have a vertex buffer for each chunk, then I run through them all, check if they're in sight and if they are I draw them.  It works fine at high fps until I have just those few extra triangles which destroy the FPS.

Edit: Added drawing code:

First I loop through all the chunks.  I check if they're visible and if they are I mark them as visible then draw them.

```
        foreach (Chunk chunk in GlobalWorld.LoadedChunks)
        {
            if (chunk == null || !chunk.DrawThis)
                continue;

            if (!player.ViewFrustrum.Intersects(chunk.Bounding))
            {
                chunk.IsInSight = false;
                continue;
            }
            chunk.IsInSight = true;

            GlobalGame.graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(chunk.VertexBuffer);
            GlobalGame.graphicsDevice.Indices = chunk.IndexBuffer;

            ChunkShader.Parameters["xWorld"].SetValue(chunk.WorldMatrix);
            ChunkShader.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
            GlobalGame.graphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, chunk.VertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0, chunk.IndexBuffer.IndexCount / 3);
        }
```

Then after that I draw all the transparent parts of the chunk (so they don't conflict with other chunks).  I already made clear if they're visible above so I just check if that bool is true.

```
        foreach (Chunk chunk in GlobalWorld.LoadedChunks)
        {
            if (chunk == null || !chunk.IsInSight || !chunk.DrawThisTransparent)
                continue;
            GlobalGame.graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(chunk.TransparentVertexBuffer);
            GlobalGame.graphicsDevice.Indices = chunk.TransparentIndexBuffer;

            ChunkTransparencyShader.Parameters["xWorld"].SetValue(chunk.WorldMatrix);
            ChunkTransparencyShader.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
            GlobalGame.graphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, chunk.TransparentVertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0, chunk.TransparentIndexBuffer.IndexCount / 3);
        }
```

With 3721 chunks loaded it runs fine with them all being drawn at the same time.  With 3844 chunks being loaded it runs fine unless you view all of them.  Now that's only just over 100 more chunks yet it's dropping from 60fps to < 1 fps.

Comment: Can you show your draw code? Are you using both an index and vertex buffer? Are you using triangles, trianglestrips or trainglelists? What kind of videocard do you have?

Comment: I have 2 vertex buffers and 2 index buffers for each chunk, 1 for transparent materials and the other for normal ones.  I added code to the original post.

Comment: So you have 6000 vertex buffers!?! 6000+ draw calls per frame is a lot.

Comment: How much total data are we talking about (bytes) and how much ram does your video card have?

Comment: I have a gtx 680 and it has 2gb of ram.  There's about 1.86e7 vertices, and 2.79e7 indices when it works at 60fps, and 1.98e7 vertices and 2.97e7 indices when it lags like crazy.  Each vertex is 8 bytes (byte4 for position and normals then halfvector2 for texture atlas coords).  And each index is 4 bytes.

(1.98e7*8+2.97e7*4) bytes in megabytes = 264.358521 megabytes

Comment: That can't be correct, HalfVector2 is 4 bytes, so that leaves you with just 4 bytes for position and normal So I'd guess it's more like 52 bytes per vertex, or if you generate the normals on the GPU something like 28 bytes (float3 is 24 bytes + 4 bytes from HV2). That would mean 922MB (24 byte vertices) or 1998MB (52 byte vertices). Now that last number seems correct since it's very close to 2GB so this could be your bottleneck.

Comment: I store it in the vertex buffer as 4 bytes for the position.  On the GPU it turns it into float4 when it draws it and turns the halfvector2 into float2 as the gpu doesn't support float16.  But that's just the drawing isn't it?  In the vertex buffer it just takes up 8 bytes per vertex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be simply running out of VRAM, causing degenerate behavior paging into/out of main RAM when rendering your scene.  How many verticies/indicies are you wrangling here? What's your vertex format like? Is this on an xbox 360 or do you have a specific GPU you can point us at?

10 million triangles x (0.5-3) verts per triangle x 5 floats (pos + 1 uv) per vert x 4 bytes per float x = **100-600MB**, and that's ignoring fragmentation, indicies, and whatever else you might have loaded (textures)

Comment: I have a gtx 680 and it has 2gb of ram. There's about 1.86e7 vertices, and 2.79e7 indices when it works at 60fps, and 1.98e7 vertices and 2.97e7 indices when it lags like crazy. Each vertex is 8 bytes (byte4 for position and normals then halfvector2 for texture atlas coords). And each index is 4 bytes. (1.98e7*8+2.97e7*4) bytes in megabytes = 264.358521 megabytes.

Copied from the above comment.

Comment: Please stop making a ridiculous number of assumption and measure you GPUs memory. http://superuser.com/questions/160291/how-can-i-monitor-video-memory-usage

Comment: I could see the driver "optimizing" those byte4s out into float4s in VRAM or something similarly silly.  I'd grab Nvidia's PerfKit if you haven't already, though, just to make sure there's nothing peculiar in those new draw calls like a bunch of transparent full screen rects.

Answer (score 1):

Mauling Monkey's answer is very right, but to solve your problem, I'll add my response.

I guess you aren't optimizing the cube faces away...
9 300 000 triangles means 4 650 000 faces. If each cube has 6 visible faces, this is 775 000 visible cubes. That number is too high. A correct number should be something like 20 000 cubes (that is how many visible cubes I have in my [CraftMania](http://2dbrothers.comuf.com/wordpress/?page_id=5), with a viewing distance of 100 meters).

Two cubes touching each other are having each one invisible face.

```
  +-----+-----+
 /     /     /|
+-----+-----+ |
|     |     | +
|     |     |/
+-----+-----+
      ^
   (They have this face in common, which is invisible.)
```

Try to implement this and your results will improve a lot!

Comment: Yeah I did have that, my view distance is about 1.4km though from corner to corner and about 1km^2.

Comment: Oh, that is a lot... To me it looks useless to set the viewing distance that high...

Comment: Really?  Larger view distances look much better.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=440YpjL54Y8

Comment: Hmm, ok looks nice!